# Simple WYSIWYG BBCode editor for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Any free and simple WYSIWYG BBCode editors for JavaScript?

Comment: I really don't get what BB is a shortcut for?

Comment: BBCode is that square-brackets thing that a lot of message boards use for markup. [b]bold[/b], [i]italic[/i] and so on.

Comment: Did you try http://www.google.com/search?q=wysiwyg+bbcode+editor+javascript ?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel for me, your link gives this very page as second result ;) I often have better results when searching on stackoverflow directly instead of google when it's programming-related

Comment: https://www.sceditor.com/ simple and MIT licence

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TinyMCE is a popular javascript WYSIWYG editor, and it supports a BBcode mode.  Here's a link to their BBcode example page:

http://tinymce.moxiecode.com/examples/example_09.php

Answer (score 5):

Are you ruling out [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)? because its open source and infinitely customizable, they have a customizable toolbar demo which includes a basic editor:

http://ckeditor.com/demo

Answer (score 2):

Is [TinyEditor](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/category/goodies/wysiwyg-html-edit/) something?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [SCEditor](https://github.com/samclarke/SCEditor)? Sounded good when I used it

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the ones listed here:-

http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/tag/bbcode/

Under the GPL license though

Answer (score 1):

http://wysiwygbbcode.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Not curently WYSIWYG

[MarkItUp](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/examples/bbcode/)

but cool editors with bbcode plugin